# React "useRef": no access to method in .current

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

So in my React Native application, I want to integrate [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-range-slider) slider, following the guidance [here](https://morioh.com/p/592c7472de8c).

Problem is, I want to get access to the method `setLowValue()` of the `.current` property of `useRef()`, as specified quite at the end of [the guidance website](https://morioh.com/p/592c7472de8c). I printed `.current` to the console and saw `setLowValue()` specified as a function, so it is definitely there. Why can't I access it?

Here is my code:

```
imports ... 

type Props = {
  size: number;
  setSize: (size: SizeState) => void;
};

const Slider: React.FC<Props> = ({size, setSize}) => {

  const slider = useRef(66); // set slider to inital value
  console.log('slider ', slider.current.initialLowValue); // doesn't work: "slider.current.initialLowValue is not a function"

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RangeSlider
        ref={slider}
        max={70}
        min={50}
        step={1}
        initialLowValue={size} // I want to have access to this property
        value={size}
        onValueChanged={value => setSize({size: value})}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    height: state.sizeResult.size,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setSize,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Slider);
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest setting the initial ref to `null`:

```js
const Slider: React.FC<Props> = ({size, setSize}) => {

  const slider = useRef(null);

  console.log('slider ', slider.current); // null

  useEffect(() => {
    if (slider.current) {
      console.log('slider ', slider.current.initialLowValue); // size
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RangeSlider
        ref={slider}
        max={70}
        min={50}
        step={1}
        initialLowValue={size} // I want to have access to this property
        value={size}
        onValueChanged={value => setSize({size: value})}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The ref values are first set on the 'componentDidMount' and 'componentDidUpdate' lifecycle states, which both occur after the first render.

The reason logging might cause confusion is because the logs can/will occur both on the first render (before componentDidMount, with the initial ref.current) and after (with a properly defined ref.current, set via the ref'd component).

The solution here is to access the ref after the component has been mounted, which can be achieved with a useEffect hook.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

tldr:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(slider.current.initialLowValue);
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
 <RangeSlider
      ref={(input) => { this.slider = input; }}
    .......
/>
```

Comment: It's not a class component and problem is not in `ref=`